# React leaflet- how to add custom components with useLeaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to create an info panel for my leaflet map like so: [leaflet-info-control](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html).
Furthermore I use **react** with **react-leaflet**. To access the global leaflet map object, react-leaflet provides the `useLeaflet()` hook.

The problem with my code is: I can see my component is rendered, but it is actually rendered behind the map. How can I add the div to/in front of the map?

### Functional Comp.

```
import {useLeaflet} from "react-leaflet";
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

function MapInfoControl({getColor}) {

    const leafletContext = useLeaflet();
    const grades = [95, 75, 50, 30, 25];

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(leafletContext) // access the LeafletContext object.
    });

    return (
        <div className="legend">
            {
                grades.map((grade, i) => (
                        <React.Fragment key={i}>
                            <i className="legend-color-box" style={{background: getColor(grades[i])}}/>
                            {
                                grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+')
                            }
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                )
            }
            )
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default MapInfoControl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will do exactly the same thing as you would do without hooks with 3 main differences:

1. create a functional component instead of a class based component
2. use `useEffect` hook instead of `componentDidMount`
3. use  `useLeaflet` hook to access the map object instead of HOC `withLeaflet`

Here is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-add-a-legend-to-the-map-using-react-leaflet-useleaflet-hook-75jnp) with a live example.

I used the example provided by Leaflet's official docs to demonstrate it.